# Stuck into bootloop, adb sideload failing

Tags: boot-loop, side-loading

I got a Nexus 5X, completely stock, no root or unlocked bootloader.

So, yesterday I remember installing a couple of games. A bit later, out of the blue, my phone reboots and I get "[Your device is corrupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xlp2.jpg)" message. The phone wouldn't boot past the Google logo and it would restart.

I went into stock recovery mode, made a wipe data and rebooted. Now the corrupt message is gone, but the phone still bootloops. It goes past the google logo, to the animation of the rotating colorful circles. However, after a few seconds the animation stops, I get a few weird lines, and the phone restarts. And this happens over and over.

I went into recovery mode again and tried to `adb sideload` the OTA. However it either gets stuck around 18%-19% or I get the error `failed to read command: no error`.

Someone suggested that my EMMC is failing. Is that true? Is there anything else I can try?

[image: Your device is corrupt]